# backbone.js error handling with laravel issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel

I have a model.save, it works fine.

```
this.model.save({
    success: function (model, response) {
        alert('hello');
    },
    error: function (model, xhr, options) {
        alert('hello');
    },
});
```

The controller is sending back 500, which i want it to right now for testing.

```
$response = [
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Cannot delete! Image is in use.'
];

return Response::json($response, 500);
```

console.log shows: POST /mysite/public/api/test 500 (Internal Server Error)

It is not alerting me 'hello', so for some reason my error callback function is not working. I can't find any problems with the syntax. Anyone else spot my problem? If so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the save method is a set of attributes to save, and the second argument is the the options hash which should contain your callbacks. Modify your call to look like this:

```
this.model.save(null, {
    success: function (model, response) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```